# In Pandas dataframe remove duplicate strings in a list column and remove the corresponding ids in the other list column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe like this:

```
df =
        A                              B

       [1, 5, 8, 10]                 [str1, str_to_be_removed*, str_to_be_removed*, str2]
       [4, 7, 10]                    [str2, str5, str10]
       [5, 2, 7, 9, 15]              [str6, str2, str_to_be_removed*, str_to_be_removed*, str_to_be_removed*]
         ...                     ...
```

Given, `str_to_be_removed`, I would like to keep only the 1st instance of the string which *contains* `str_to_be_removed`, in column B and remove the other ones. In addition, I would also like to remove the corresponding ids from A. Size of lists contained in A and B in each row is the same.

How to do this?

Desired Output:

```
       df = 

       A                           B
      
      [1, 5, 10]                  [str1, str_to_be_removed*, str2]
      [4, 7, 10]                  [str2, str5, str10]
      [5, 2, 7]                   [str6, str2, str_to_be_removed*]
```

EDIT:

```
So, this is the sample df:

   df =
       df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5]],[10,11,12]\
               'B':[['str_to_be_removed_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla'],['str_to_be_removed_bla','b'],['b','c','d'],\
                    ['str_to_be_removed_bla_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla','f']\
                   ]})


  Desired Output:

    df =
    
    A                      B

    [1]                    [str_to_be_removed_bla]
    [2,3]                  [str_to_be_removed_bla, b]
    [3,4,5]                [b, c, d]
    [10, 12]               [str_to_be_removed_bla_bla,f]
```

Comment: Explode them to rows. Delete dups. Bring them back to lists. Thats one way to do it.

Comment: I am afraid, that would be too expensive to perform as lists are really large.

Comment: can you do df.head(5).to_dict()?

Comment: @BENY, I am not sure, I full follow, what would that achieve?

Comment: Help us create your dataframe easily

Comment: Right, this was just a dummy. My original has really large lists with 500 elements in both `A` and `B`. Let me get back with something, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

steps:

1. <s>use `zip` to combine relate elements together.</s>
2. <s>unnest the zip list</s>, use `explode`
3. drop duplicates, keep first
4. goupby index, agg as list.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[
            [1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5],[10, 11, 12] 
        ],
       'B':[['str_to_be_removed_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla'], 
            ['str_to_be_removed_bla','b'],
            ['b', 'c', 'd'],
            ['str_to_be_removed_bla_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla','f']
           ]})

# zip and explode step 
# df_obj = df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.A, x.B)),
#         axis = 1
#        ).to_frame()
# df_obj = df_obj.explode(0).reset_index()
# df_obj['A'] = df_obj[0].str[0]
# df_obj['B'] = df_obj[0].str[1]
```

update with @Joe Ferndz's solution, simplify the steps.

```py
# explode the columns
dfTemp = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
df_obj = dfTemp.reset_index()

# can add more conditions to filter and handle to drop_duplicates
cond = df_obj['B'].astype(str).str.contains("str_to_be_removed")
df1 = df_obj[cond].drop_duplicates(['index'], keep='first')
df2 = df_obj[~cond]
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
result = df3.groupby('index').agg({'A':list, 'B':list})
```

result

```
               A                               B
index                                           
0            [1]         [str_to_be_removed_bla]
1         [2, 3]      [str_to_be_removed_bla, b]
2      [3, 4, 5]                       [b, c, d]
3       [10, 12]  [str_to_be_removed_bla_bla, f]
```

---

extend this solution to multiple patterns in 1 step: str_to_be_removed1, str_to_be_removed2,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[
            [1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5, 6],[10, 11, 12] 
        ],
       'B':[['str_to_be_removed1_bla','str_to_be_removed1_bla'], 
            ['str_to_be_removed1_bla','b'],
            ['b', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
            ['str_to_be_removed2_bla_bla','str_to_be_removed2_bla','f']
           ]})
print(df)

#               A                                                        B
# 0        [1, 2]         [str_to_be_removed1_bla, str_to_be_removed1_bla]
# 1        [2, 3]                              [str_to_be_removed1_bla, b]
# 2  [3, 4, 5, 6]                                             [b, b, c, d]
# 3  [10, 11, 12]  [str_to_be_removed2_bla_bla, str_to_be_removed2_bla, f]
```

```
df_obj = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode()).reset_index()
df_obj['tag'] = df_obj['B'].str.extract(r'(str_to_be_removed1|str_to_be_removed2)')
print(df_obj)

#     index   A                           B                 tag
# 0       0   1      str_to_be_removed1_bla  str_to_be_removed1
# 1       0   2      str_to_be_removed1_bla  str_to_be_removed1
# 2       1   2      str_to_be_removed1_bla  str_to_be_removed1
# 3       1   3                           b                 NaN
# 4       2   3                           b                 NaN
# 5       2   4                           b                 NaN
# 6       2   5                           c                 NaN
# 7       2   6                           d                 NaN
# 8       3  10  str_to_be_removed2_bla_bla  str_to_be_removed2
# 9       3  11      str_to_be_removed2_bla  str_to_be_removed2
# 10      3  12                           f                 NaN

cond = df_obj['tag'].notnull()
df1 = df_obj[cond].drop_duplicates(['index', 'tag'], keep='first')
df2 = df_obj[~cond]
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
print(df3.groupby('index').agg({'A':list, 'B':list}))
#                   A                                B
# index                                               
# 0               [1]         [str_to_be_removed1_bla]
# 1            [2, 3]      [str_to_be_removed1_bla, b]
# 2      [3, 4, 5, 6]                     [b, b, c, d]
# 3          [10, 12]  [str_to_be_removed2_bla_bla, f]
```

Comment: I wanted to use drop_duplicates keep first. However, I realized that the data contains `[str_to_be_removed_bla_bla, str_to_be_removed_bla, f]` Here drop duplicates will NOT give the desired result

Comment: oh, I might misunderstand what you mean. I'll replace `df_obj[cond].drop_duplicates(['index', 'B'], keep='first')` with `df_obj[cond].drop_duplicates(['index'], keep='first')`. I don't know if it is satisfied.

Comment: you can add `.reset_index()` to the end of explode(). Also, you dont need to do `.astype(str).str.`. just `['B'].str.contains` will do

Comment: @Ferris, why do you reset index, is that necessary?

Comment: I am trying out your solution, now

Comment: @Ferris, how can I extend this solution to multiple patterns in 1 step: str_to_be_removed1, str_to_be_removed2, ... Is it possible? I want to keep 1st row of each pattern and discard everything else.

Comment: @SumitSidana How about extract the patterns to a new column `tag`, and drop duplicated with index and tag. I'll update this method in my solution.

Comment: @Ferris actually now, I just wrote a function with your solution and call this function for each pattern and keep returning the updated data frame. I pass pattern and updated df as parameters. That seems to be working fine. It takes a bit of time, but yeah, if it can be done in 1 step, that would indeed be neat.

Comment: I have updated my answers, I hope it will work.

Comment: by the way, the `reset_index` is necessary, it is a clue of every single row, as you only want to drop duplicates on each row.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an another approach to do this. Here' you can give the search string and it will remove it from the list.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4,5],[10,11,12]],
                   'B':[['str_to_be_removed_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla'],
                        ['str_to_be_removed_bla','b'],
                        ['b','c','d'],
                        ['str_to_be_removed_bla_bla','str_to_be_removed_bla','f']]})
print (df)

search_str = 'str_to_be_removed'

#explode each column into its own rows
dfTemp = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())

#flag columns that contains search string
dfTemp['Found'] = dfTemp.B.str.contains(search_str)

#cumcount by Index and by search strings to get duplicates
dfTemp['Bx'] = dfTemp.groupby([dfTemp.index,'Found']).cumcount()

#Exclude all records where search string was found and count is more than 1
dfTemp = dfTemp[~(dfTemp['Found'] & dfTemp['Bx'] > 0)]

#Extract back all the records into the dataframe and store as list
df_final = dfTemp.groupby(dfTemp.index).agg({'A':list, 'B':list})

del dfTemp

print (df_final)
```

The output of this is:

Original dataframe:

```
              A                                                      B
0        [1, 2]         [str_to_be_removed_bla, str_to_be_removed_bla]
1        [2, 3]                             [str_to_be_removed_bla, b]
2     [3, 4, 5]                                              [b, c, d]
3  [10, 11, 12]  [str_to_be_removed_bla_bla, str_to_be_removed_bla, f]
```

search string: `'str_to_be_removed'`

Final dataframe:

```
           A                               B
0        [1]         [str_to_be_removed_bla]
1     [2, 3]      [str_to_be_removed_bla, b]
2  [3, 4, 5]                       [b, c, d]
3   [10, 12]  [str_to_be_removed_bla_bla, f]
```

Comment: thanks to @Ferris for groupby agg list solution. updated my last line to make it easier rather than apply lambda function

Comment: Thx, `df.apply(lambda x: x.explode())` is impress.

Comment: yeah. You can take care of df_obj with just this one line. You dont need to zip it. Go ahead and change your code if this is a better approach to get to the exploded list of both columns. The beauty is that it can explode as many columns as needed and does not worry too much about how many values it has.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try dict

```
out = pd.DataFrame([[list(dict(zip(y[::-1],x[::-1])).values())[::-1],list(dict(zip(y[::-1],x[::-1])).keys())[::-1]]  for x , y in zip(df.A,df.B)])
out
        0       1
0     [1]     [a]
1  [2, 2]  [a, b]
```

Sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[2,2]],'B':[['a','a'],['a','b']]})
```

Comment: Hi @BENY, I added a sample df with 3 rows and expected output. Please also note the `contains` relationship. I am given a `str_to_be_removed` and I would like to remove all the strings which `contains` `str_to_be_removed` except the 1st one and corresponding ids in `A`.

Comment: @SumitSidana that make the question even time consuming , so you may format the string first before remove it

Comment: Right, I can try doing that, but, even then, it is preserving the later id, when I want the 1st id. Do you know how to solve that problem? I want the 1st id, containing the duplicate, not the second one.

Comment: Also, my problem is that I want to do it only for `str_to_be_removed` and not any other duplicates. Is it making sense?

Comment: @SumitSidana check the update , adding [::-1]

Comment: Now it is giving the right ids, but reverses the original order

Comment: @SumitSidana please check ~

Comment: Hi @BENY, it is fine, now for all the duplicate strings, thanks a lot! I will just wait a little before accepting, if someone can give an answer for a `given specific string` and with `contains` constraint, if that is ok

Answer (score 1):

Don't think a native pandas solution is possible for this case. And even there is, you are not likely to have a performance gain with it. A traditional for loop might work better for your case:

```
def remove_dupes(a, b, dupe_pattern):
  seen_dupe = False
  _a, _b = [], []
  for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if dupe_pattern in y:
      if not seen_dupe:
        seen_dupe = True
        _a.append(x)
        _b.append(y)
    else:
      _a.append(x)
      _b.append(y)
  return _a, _b

_A, _B = [], []

for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B):
  _a, _b = remove_dupes(a, b, 'str_to_be_removed')
  _A.append(_a)
  _B.append(_b)

df['A'], df['B'] = _A, _B
print(df)

#           A                               B
#0        [1]         [str_to_be_removed_bla]
#1     [2, 3]      [str_to_be_removed_bla, b]
#2  [3, 4, 5]                       [b, c, d]
#3   [10, 12]  [str_to_be_removed_bla_bla, f]
```

Try run it [here](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/4af652d5.py).

Comment: I think there is and I don't think the performance is that bad